# Skip one string in regex

Tags: regex, apache, apache-config

I have the following apache rewrite rule:

```
000-default.conf:    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

How would I change this to allow everything except if the following string is in the url: `tab=availability` ?

Comment: @MarcB could you please show in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negation in `RewriteRule` itself:

```
RewriteRule !tab=availability https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```

This will redirect all the requests with URI not containing given pattern. However if you are using above rule in `.htaccess` then better to add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

to avoid redirect loop.

Moreover if you want to avoid matching given pattern **anywhere** in URL including `QUERY_STRING` then use `THE_REQUEST` variable in your condition:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !tab=availability [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R]
```